# MongoDB aggregation query, return collections that that are refs on model, based on a paramater

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have the following query,

```
MyModel.aggregate([
    {
      $project: {
        field: 1,
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "AnotherModel",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "someField",
        as: "field"
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: "$_id"
      }
    }
])
```

This works executes, but not as expected. In `AnotherModel`, there is a field called `show`, and I want this query to return `MyModel` collections, only where `show` is set to true on `AnotherModel`. I tried,

```
MyModel.aggregate([
    {
      $project: {
        field: 1,
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "AnotherModel",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "someField",
        as: "field"
      },
      $where: {
        show: true // <-- this part
      }
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: "$_id"
      }
    }
])
```

But that threw an error. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you post please sample data to reproduce your queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one: [Uncorrelated Sub-queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

```
MyModel.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      field: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "AnotherModel",
      let: {
        id: "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            show: true,
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$someField",
                "$$id"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "field"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$_id"
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sD00oKf30AE)